# LUIS.ai returns different intents for almost similar utterances

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I use LUIS as a Language Understanding Service for our Chat Bot built with Microsoft Bot Framework.
And I observe the strange behavior:

1. I added a string *"what is my deductible?"* to the intent *"Deductible"*.
2. A user sends *"what is my deductible"* string ---> LUIS returns the desired intent "Deductible". **OK!**
3. A user sends *"what is my deductibl?"* OR *"what is my deductible"* (misspelling in the first case, lack of a question mark in the second case) ---> LUIS returns some other intents (which are not related to deductible AT ALL). **NOT OK!**
4. Also, I don't see any utterances like those in "Review Endpoint Utterances" section so I could reassign the utterances to the desired intent. **NOT OK AT ALL!**

Any ideas how to fix it, how to improve the recognition for utterances with **misspellings**, **lack of symbols** and also - it's very important - with **synonyms** of the words?

Answer (score 0):

To improve the utterances with misspellings, lack of symbols and other requirements, there is a need to add the templates of utterance using correct syntax.

**misspellings**

The below code is V2 prediction end point

```
{
  "query": "Book a flite to London?",
  "alteredQuery": "Book a flight to London?",
  "topScoringIntent": {
    "intent": "BookFlight",
    "score": 0.780123
  },
  "entities": []
}
```

The below code is V3 prediction end point

```
{
    "query": "Book a flite to London?",
    "prediction": {
        "normalizedQuery": "book a flight to london?",
        "topIntent": "BookFlight",
        "intents": {
            "BookFlight": {
                "score": 0.780123
            }
        },
        "entities": {},
    }
}
```

To perform the utterances perfect creation using valid syntaxes, Using the following resources.

https://blog.botframework.com/2018/06/07/improving-accuracy-in-luis-with-patterns/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-model-intent-pattern

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-data-alteration?tabs=V3